# best way to find highest key value in entity framework datacontext and local unsaved changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using an EF code first datacontext, and I am looking for a way to get the highest value of the primary key field for a given entity collection which is a bit more elegant than what I have.

Currently I am using the following:

```
internal long GetHighestIdForProductGroups()
    {
        //s200 is the name of my data context
        long stored  = s200.ProductGroups.Count()> 0? s200.ProductGroups.Max(x => x.ProductGroupID) : 0;
        var local = s200.ProductGroups.Local.Count() > 0 ? s200.ProductGroups.Max(x => x.ProductGroupID) :0;
        return Math.Max(stored, local);
    }
```

This may be called before the DB has been generated, with some data in the DB or not, and also with some or no data in the local cache...

Comment: s200.ProductGroups.OrderBy(...).LastOrDefault()?

Comment: LastOrDefault cannot be translated into a store expression

Comment: Like @DeblatonJean-Philippe said: `s200.ProductGroups.OrderByDescending(x => x.ProductGroupID).FirstOrDefault()`?

Answer (score 0):

Casting to `Nullable<int>` makes this at least a little shorter:

```
long stored = s200.ProductGroups.Max(p => (int?)p.ProductGroupID) ?? 0;
long local = s200.ProductGroups.Local.Max(p => (int?)p.ProductGroupID) ?? 0;

var max = Math.Max(stored, local);
```

Using `Max` on a nullable will return `null` if the collection is empty.

What would also work is getting the combined maximum from the concatenated IDs, sending the local IDs to the server and let the database evaluate the maximum:

```
var max = s200.ProductGroups
                .Select(p => p.ProductGroupID)
                .Concat(s200.ProductGroups.Local
                            .Select(p => p.ProductGroupID)
                            .ToArray())
                .Max(id => (int?) id)
            ?? 0;
```

This actually works, but for two local items with IDs 20 and 24 it generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        MAX([UnionAll2].[ProductGroupID]) AS [A1]
        FROM  (SELECT 
            [Extent1].[ProductGroupID] AS [ProductGroupID]
            FROM [dbo].[ProductGroups] AS [Extent1]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            [UnionAll1].[C1] AS [C1]
            FROM  (SELECT 
                20 AS [C1]
                FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
            UNION ALL
                SELECT 
                24 AS [C1]
                FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable2]) AS [UnionAll1]) AS [UnionAll2]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

Nobody would want that.